# `source $MYVIMRC` doesn't work when i delete some content, but it does work when i add some content

Tags: vim

`:source $MYVIMRC` doesn't work when I delete some content in .vimrc, but it will work when I add some content.

I want to enable a setting which is typing `@@` then it will automatically show my email, so I add a line in my .vimrc file like this `iabbrev @@ XXX@gmail.com` and `:w` to save the file. After that, I turn to my source file, then I type `:source $MYVIMRC`, It works as expected. BUT, If I remove the line `iabbrev @@ xxx@gmail.com` and save .vimrc file.  Again, I turn to my source file, then I type `:source $MYVIMRC`, It still works. Only I quit the file and reopen it. The changes can effect. How can I make the DELETE changes effect without quitting the file?

Comment out the line is the same as removing the line. `:source $MYVIMRC` doesn't effect. It effects only I quit the file and reopen it the newer .vimrc will work.

I am not a native speaker, please ask me if you don't understand my problem.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Think of it this way: Vim has a *runtime model* that contains all the options, mappings, custom commands, etc. that are currently active; this lives inside Vim's memory. On startup, Vim builds this model through defaults that are built-in, plus any user configuration like your `~/.vimrc` and plugins that you have installed. When you `:source` your config (or a plugin), Vim basically just updated stuff that's already there and hasn't changed, and any *additions* are introduced to the runtime model.

In order to remove stuff, **the easiest way is to simply quit Vim and restart it**. The whole process of building the runtime model will start again, and anything you've removed from your configuration won't be there any longer.

Alternatively, you'd have to explicitly remove stuff from the runtime model; for most stuff, there are corresponding negating commands:

- For options, you can restore the default via [`:help :set-&`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%3Aset-%26)
- The inverse of `:map` is `:unmap`. For your example, the inverse of `:iabbrev @@ ...` is `:iunabbrev @@`.
- There's `:command` and `:delcommand`.
- `:autocmd` can be removed via `:autocmd!`: Cp. [`:help autocmd-remove`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#autocmd-remove)

As you can see, there are ways, but their use is somewhat inconsistent. Unless you have a lot of state in the editor (many opened files, customizations not persisted in the config yet, etc.), quitting and re-opening Vim is easier.

#### Limiting the scope of customizations

Sometimes, you want an abbreviation or setting just for a certain buffer. Some people try to solve this by defining and undefining stuff, but this is clumsy and wrong: Vim has support for that in the form of *filetype plugins* ([`:help ftplugin`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_41.txt.html#ftplugin)). By using `:setlocal` instead of `:set`, and `:map <buffer>`, `:abbreviate <buffer>`, `:command -buffer`, that customization will only apply to buffers of that filetype (e.g. Java files, but not Python code). If you interactively type such a command, it will only be available in the *current* buffer, and nowhere else.

Comment: It works fine with `unmap` and `iunabbrev xxx` , but it seems like not good for `autocmd!`. For example, I use `autocmd FileType cpp nnoremap <buffer> <F8> : xxxxx` to compile and run the cpp source, and then as you say, I type `autocmd! filetype cpp` to disable all the autocmd at cpp files, BUT as I type `F8`, It still compile and run as often. I checked the autocmd list by typing `autocmd filetype cpp`, it shows me there isn't any autocmd, but why it still works? Did I miss something? I have read the manual several times and still can't figure out the problem.

Comment: The same applies here: The `:autocmd` has done its job to define the mapping once the buffer is loaded. By removing it, you only turn off definition of the mapping for _future_ buffers. The mapping in the current buffer will remain. You need to explicitly `:nunmap <buffer> <F8>` it (or just close the buffer with `:close`).